# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource + 'it does not have http ok status' when CORS extension enabled

Tags: javascript, http, request

I was trying to do a simple website that prints the remaining time of different buses. I'm using the transporter's API:

```
function getTime(){
    fetch("https://prim.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/marketplace/stop-monitoring/?MonitoringRef=STIF:StopPoint:Q:37144:", {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "apiKey": "NoAPIKeyForU",
        "accept": "application/json"
    },})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    return response.text();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
});
};
getTime();
```

My website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="details">
        
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After testing this code on my website, I got this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://prim.iledefrance-mobilites.fr/marketplace/stop-monitoring/?MonitoringRef=STIF:StopPoint:Q:37144:' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How can I fix this?

I tried:

- The CORS extension, giving me another error: "It does not have http ok status"
- `.htaccess`, nothing
- CORS Proxy, I don't know how to use it

Comment: That API endpoint is preventing you from doing this as a security measure. To work around this you need to make the API call from a server you build, and then call your own server to get the data.

Comment: @Evert and how can i do that ?, i got no knowledge about making servers

Comment: Then you need to attain that knowledge.